# Javascript - fixed table header on scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a code pen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKrmOo

I have a table with content above it

When the page scrolls and the table gets to the top of the page I need the table header to be sticky
and the table contents 5to scroll underneath.

I need to keep the table header in its position on top of the table as the table scroll left to right as well

I have made at attempt at the javascript but I'm using a fixed number for the pageYOffset but I dont know what this will be so I need it be when the table reaches the top of the page.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var tableHeader = document.getElementById('thead');
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  tableHeader.classList.add("sticky");
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 200) {
    tableHeader.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    tableHeader.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "fixed" instead of sticky?

Comment: In the CSS? I'm using `position: fixed;` now

Comment: Yes to the CSS. You might want to try the JQuery solution too "element.addClass(" yourClass");"  Do you have a CSS class named "sticky" or are you trying to set the position attribute to sticky?

Comment: I cant use `position: sticky;` because I need to try and support IE11

Comment: What about "position: fixed;"? For IE11, you may need "position: expression(fixed);"

Comment: I missed the example link you posted... I'd start with moving " "id="thead"" to the <thead> element first and work from there.